# Getting an error while converting a tex template to pdf

Tags: fonts, miktex

I am trying to open a tex template from a journal. But I'm getting an error while trying to compile that template to pdf. It says "Pk font ec-qagb could not be created".

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about how you set up the MikTeX distribution. In particular, did you install a full version of MikTeX, i.e., with all packages, or did you install a "basic" version. If you chose the latter, did you set it up so that it can search for, download, and install any missing packages (including font-related packages)? Please advise.

Comment: Incidentally, did you take a look at the contents of the log file, *viz.*, `C:\Users\sanjo\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log`? (That's what the screenshot you posted suggests you do...) If so, what does the file say?

Comment: ec-qagb is a reference to a tex gyre font. These are type1 fonts and shouldn't trigger makepk, so probably your map-files are not up-to-date. Run on a command line `updmap` or in the miktex console (user mode), menu task "recreate font map files".

Answer (score 1):

`ec-qagb` is a reference to a tex gyre font.

These are type1 fonts and shouldn't trigger `makepk`, so probably your map-files are not up-to-date.

Run on a command line `updmap` (as user)  or in the miktex console (user mode) in the menu `Tasks` the entry `Refresh font map files`.

[image]